# PWA - Why has my caching strategy such a negative impact on the performance?

Tags: performance, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, lighthouse

So I am currently building my first pwa and I don't understand why the way I implemented caching, has such bad influence on the performance (LightHouse Performance Score drops from ~94 to 76 with a huge Increase (+4 seconds) in the LCP Score and I honestly don't get what I am doing wrong here.

The app is a blogging app and later on, I want to make whole articles available for offline use. For now, I did not want to do anything fancy, I just wanted to make the landingpage (which does not contain any mongo db queries, but many images and css) available for offline use.

So the Idea is the following:

1. Interrupt the fetch request
2. Check if the data is available in the cache

   - if yes: serve from the cache
   - if no: proceed with the fetch request

Implementation:

I have the following setup:

- Node JS - blogging app (server-side rendered)
- hooked up with a mongo db database
- in combo with ejs templates

by entering: localhost:8000

the server responds with the ejs file that corresponds to landingpage with partials, that include the header and the footer.

```
app.get("/", resetVerifiedVariable, (req, res) => {
  res.render("home.ejs");
});
```

This is the corresponding header , in which I make sure that the service worker is registered

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/icons/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="preload" href="/img/upchart-mobile.webp" as="image" />
  <link rel="preload" href="css/main.css" as="style" />

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1045be" />

  <!-- ios support for pwa -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icons/icon-96x96.png" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-status-bar" content="#1045be" />

<!-- REGISTER SERVICE WORKER -->
  <script src="/scripts/initiateServiceWorker.js"></script>
<!-- REGISTER SERVICE WORKER -->


  <!-- typeofOperator does not throw an error  so we can check for the existence of an article-->
  <% if (typeof article !== 'undefined') { %>
  <title><%=article.title%>| title </title>

  <!-- Meta Tags for Social Media sharing the articles  -->

  <meta
    property="og:url"
    content="https://example.com/blog/<%=article.slug%>"
  />
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="<%=article.title%>" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="<%=article.metaDescription%>" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="./img/logo-optimized.webp" />
  <%} else { %>
  <title>Title| Title </title>
  <meta
    name="description"
    content="Description"
  />
  <%}%>
</head>
```

Here is the corresponding Service Worker File that was hooked-up in the header:

```
// ###################################
//    REGISTER SERVICE WORKER - PWA
// ###################################
// Check if the browser supports the serviceWorker

if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  //console.log(navigator.serviceWorker);
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register("../serviceWorker.js")
    .then((registrationObject) =>
      console.log("ServiceWorker registered", registrationObject)
    )
    .catch((error) => console.log("ServiceWorker NOT registered", error));
}
```

With that out of the way, I have implemented the Cache

I want to cahce the following items:
-The html/ejs template for the landingpage
-The image from the Hero section
-All of the css
-and my main script

```
const staticCacheName = "staticServiceWorker-v1";

const staticAssets = ["/", "/img/upchart-mobile.webp", "/scripts/index.js", "css/main.css];



// ############################
// INSTALL
// ############################
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  const preCache = async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open(staticCacheName);
    // addAll returns a promise which must be passed on to waitUntil
    return cache.addAll(staticAssets);
  };
  event.waitUntil(preCache());
});

//console.log("ServiceWorker installed");

//

// ############################
// ACTIVATE
// ############################
self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  //console.log("ServiceWorker activated");
});

// ############################
// FETCH
// ############################

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  console.log(event);

  const checkCacheMatch = async () => {
    const result = await caches.match(event.request);

    return result || fetch(event.request);
  };
  event.respondWith(checkCacheMatch());
});
```

In the Fetch-Block I try to interrupt the fetch and serve the files from the cache instead

I assume, that this block right here is causing the performance decrease, but I dont know how to make this more performant.

So the main goal was to make the page much more performant because I make use of the cache and would there would be no need for a server request. What happens however is the exact opposite  and I honestly can not figure out why that is the case

Any help would much appreciated

BR